# Update key in nested document

Tags: mongodb

I would like to update the keys of the object "values" in the following document stored in a MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Doe",
        "values": {
            "AA_Avg": 13,
            "BB_Avg": 19,
            "CC_Avg": 18
        }
    }
}
```

To make it looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Doe",
        "values": {
            "AA_MT": 13,
            "BB_MT": 19,
            "CC_MT": 18
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic update you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

**First approach:** using [`$rpelaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/#exp._S_replaceOne),

- `$objectToArray` convert `data.values` from object to array in k and v format
- `$map` to iterate loop of above converted array
- `$replaceOne` will replace string on the base of input and replacement
- `$arrayToObject` back to convert from array to object

```
db.collection.update({},
  [{
    $set: {
      "data.values": {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$data.values" },
            in: {
              k: {
                $replaceOne: {
                  input: "$$this.k",
                  find: "Avg",
                  replacement: "MT"
                }
              },
              v: "$$this.v"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K5W-ZQlUoE8)

---

**Second approach:** using `$split`, `$arrayElemAt`, `$concat`,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RHxnLP9qiVk)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. It works perfectly in the mongo playground but i got an error when i tried it in my mongo console.
 "code" : 52,                                                                                                                        
 "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$arrayToObject' in 'data.values.$arrayToObject' is not valid for storage.",
Any suggestion ?

Comment: what is the version of your mongodb and mongo shell?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.0.1
I use the bitnami/mongodb:latest image which is the version 4.4.3 https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/blob/4.4.3-debian-10-r30/4.4/debian-10/Dockerfile

Comment: I am not sure but try updating mongo shell version to 4.2 or greater, sorry i really don't have any knowledge about bitami/mongodb docker.

Comment: Yes !!! By updating to the latest version it works !!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) function like this:

Is simply, you only have to say what field do you want to update and the new value.

Note that due to nested objects you have to use dot notation as explained into [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

> MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and **to access the fields of an embedded document**.

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$rename": {
    "data.values.AA_Avg": "data.values.AA_MT",
    "data.values.CC_Avg": "data.values.BB_MT",
    "data.values.DD_Avg": "data.values.CC_MT"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0_OrKIOmJri)